# Windows -- inherit console file handle in child process

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, win32-process

I have a Windows application (`subsystem=windows`, not a console application). I am creating a console in that application, then creating a child process. When I  create the console, I make a console file handle inheritable (see below). When I create the child process, I set the `bInheritHandles` argument of `CreateProcess` to `TRUE`. I want the child process to be able to read to and write from the console, but I get error `0x06`, `invalid handle`.

I do the following:

1) `AllocConsole();`

2) `CreateFile("CONIN$", ...)`, `CreateFile("CONOUT$", ...)` or
`CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(...)` with the following `SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(...)`. Always have `SecurityAttributes` with `bInheritHandle=TRUE`.
but see `bInheritHandle=1`.

3) `CreateProcess(NULL, GetCommandLine(), NULL, NULL,
TRUE, /* inherit handles */ 0, NULL, NULL, &sinfo, &child);`

In child process:

1) `_open_osfhandle((intptr_t)console_handle, 0)` gives me `-1` and `GetLastError()` returns error `0x06` -- `"Invalid handle"`.

The child process is a copy of its parent, so both processes have the same subsystem: `windows` (not console application).

I have checked that other file handles are inherited normally and can be used with `fdopen(_open_osfhandle(file_handle), ...)`. For example, it works for a text file. But it doesn't work for a console handle.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing in step 2, or where the child process gets the value of `console_handle` from. Please show some actual code.

Comment: Console handles are pseudo handles that refer to the current process's console.  If the child process is a windows app then it won't have a console when you launch it so a handle that refers to the current console is meaningless.

Comment: Do you call `SetStdHandle()` in parent prog? And see this to inherit console in child gui http://hg.netbeans.org/main-golden/file/2da7b1f9de9b/o.n.bootstrap/launcher/windows/utilsfuncs.cpp#l343

Answer (score 0):

Yes, arx (see comments above) absolutelly right: console file handle is "fake" handle as it not exists at OS level (and can not be inherited). This type of file handle is only known for Win32 api libraries (kernel32.dll) and I/O requests processed at this level only. Windows doesn't have real console files, as virtual terminals in Unix (except of Windows8). :-(  So, I need to change subsystem of my application from "windows" type to "console" and then application can use pre-allocated console (but file handle still can't be inherited -- need to reopen "CONOUT$" in child process...)